# ScrollView is not working in CarouselViewControl

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, scrollview, carousel

I am using `CarouselView` where I even want to scroll vertically, so I placed a `ScollView` with vertical orientation but the view is not scrolling vertically.

```
<StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="7">
    <abstractions:CarouselViewControl x:Name="QuestionCarousel" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Position="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Questions}">
        <abstractions:CarouselViewControl.HeightRequest>
            <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments ="x:Double" Phone="260" Tablet="400"/>
        </abstractions:CarouselViewControl.HeightRequest>
        <abstractions:CarouselViewControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ScrollView Orientation="Vertical">
                    <StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ScrollView>
            </DataTemplate>
        </abstractions:CarouselViewControl.ItemTemplate>
    </abstractions:CarouselViewControl>
```

Is there any way to get vertical scroll here?

Comment: Does yout `StackLayout` contain anything?

Comment: Yes,It contains a frame with editor and few buttons.

Answer (score 0):

If **ScrollView** is the parent wrapper then it won’t work. Wrap it within **StackLayout** and you should be good.